# Has any version of Marvel's Black Panther ever been able to actually turn into a Were-Panther form?

Tags: marvel, alternate-history, black-panther

I *know* I saw this somewhere, possibly in another reality outside of 616.

In that version, T'Challa (the Black Panther) seemed to "shift" into a humanoid panther form, very similar to Wolfbane's "mid way" form.

Can someone please point out what version, comic, film or alternate show where this takes place, and explain how it happens?

By that, I mean was it a side affect of the heart shape herb, was it a mutation of the Wakandan royal family, or was it accomplished via some form of device?

Comment: You’re looking for answers on T’Challa only or any other versions of Black panther are acceptable? Like t’chaka for example?

Comment: I would be _most_ interested in T'Challa, but considering the "Black Panther" is a title that is passed on, any holder of that title would be a valid example. So yeah, please feel free to sharer them if you have them, and explain _how_ and _why_ he or she had this power.

Comment: the reason I asked you is that I remember seeing T'Chaka turning into a were-panther somewhere. I could look for it if its needed as well.

Comment: As far as i can remember the Marvel mangaverse Black panther has the ability to become a Were-Panther, and falcon too if he wants to.
Black panther of Earth X is also a permanent Were-Panther. I should write this up as an answer but i have not the time right now, but if someone else want to, feel free.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### The Black Panther (T'Challa) is able to transform into a were-panther in the Marvel Mangaverse

In *Marvel's Mangaverse* designated as Earth-2301, T'Challa is able to transform into a Were-panther. In *Marvel Mangaverse Issue #4*, when Doctor Doom attacks the UN summit, T'Challa is shown to transform into a were-panther (*image below*). However, this is supposed to be his normal ability (as opposed to the other Marvel universes where he wears a suit).

[image]
<sub>*Marvel Mangaverse Issue #4*</sub>

Addressing the second part of your question, this transformation is neither related to the heart-shaped herb nor is it any hereditary trait. On the contrary, the power of the Black Panther is granted by a spirit (or some deity probably) called **Qamatha**.

> **T'Challa**: Great Qamatha! Fill my soul with your spirit! Make me BLACK PANTHER!
>  
>   <sub>*Marvel Mangaverse Issue #4*</sub>

---

Considering you'd also like some other instances, **King T'Chaka** was also able to transform into a Were-Panther. In the animated movie *Ultimate Avengers*, when Herr Kleiser attacked Wakanda with his Chitauri army, the Black Panther's mantle was still with T'Chaka. He tried to defend his kingdom but was ultimately killed in the process. However, during this time, we do see T'Chaka transform into a were-panther (watch the video below; transformation at the 3:00 mark)

Comment: Awesome. I beive _the movie_ is where I got the inkling from it; saw a clip of it years ago and wondered if this was canon. Thank you, this answers it marvelously.

Comment: @RussRainford heh, "marvelously". nice.